# Blocking a user after incorrect logins using Ajax timer control

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, authentication, timer

i want to Block a user from login in for 5 minutes when he  enters a wrong password.i am disabling the submit button for this by using timer control but i am confused as to how to enable the button after 5 minutes. if i enable it in the page load. the button gets enables after every post back or merely a refresh. here z a screen shot of the code so far...

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    en.Log_Username = TextBox1.Text;
    en.Log_Password = TextBox2.Text;
    dt = new DataTable();
    dt = bll.log_Login(en);
    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        Session["emp_Mobile"] = en.Log_Password;
        Session["emp_Username"] = en.Log_Username;
        Response.Redirect("Calling.aspx");
        //Response.Redirect("Calling.aspx?emp_Mobile=" + Server.UrlEncode(en.Log_Password) + "&emp_Username=" + Server.UrlEncode(en.Log_Username));
    }
    else
    {
        Label1.Text = "Incorrect Username or Password";
        int count = 0;
        if (Session["incorrect"] != null)
        {
            count = Convert.ToInt32(Session["incorrect"]);
            Session["incorrect"] = count + 1;             
        }
        else
        {
            count = count + 1;
            Session["incorrect"] = count;
        }

        if (count >2)
        {
            Label1.Text = "You've Entered Wrong Password  3 times, Please wait for sometime!";
            Timer1_Tick(sender, e);


        }
    }
}
protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button1.Enabled = false;

}
```

Comment: Please post your code as text

Comment: i got it working by removing the Button1.Enabled from page load....
the only thing is that the label is not printing error message now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, i had Removed

```
Button1.Enabled=true;
```

From Page_Load
and the above code works fine blocking the user to log-in for 5 minutes by disabling the submit button.

just set the `Interval="3000000"` in asp:Timer Control.

Answer (score 1):

you need to write some client side javascript to do that. javascript has a function setTimeout which can help. you can also look into using a cookie to record when was the last login attempt to prevent the page refresh situation.

still this is not a very good solution, if you want to enforce the rule you need to do it on the server as well. in your database record the time of the last unsuccessful login attempt and do not allow user to login before the desired time elapses.

Comment: Thanks man . i'm kinda a new in development thing... still learning :)